# Problema ao mostrar data no Android

Tags: java, android, data

Ao exibir uma data que foi inserida no banco de dados, do tipo `DateTime`, o app mostra a data atual:

[image: Data atual errada]

Também gostaria de converter essa data para **dd/mm/aaaa** para ajustar a um layout retrato.

Parte do código que trata essa lista:

```
public List<Despesa> getLista() {
    Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().query(TABELA, COLUNAS, null, null, null, null, null);
    List<Despesa> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        java.util.Date parsedDate = new java.util.Date();
        String a = c.getString(1);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
        SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        try {
            parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(a);
            a = parsedDate.toString();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     //   String returnDate=outputFormatTime.format(inputFormat);

        Despesa despesa = new Despesa();
        despesa.setValor(c.getFloat(0));
        despesa.setData(parsedDate);
        despesa.setDescricao(c.getString(2));
        despesa.setPago(c.getString(3).equalsIgnoreCase("TRUE"));
        despesa.setIdSubgrupo(c.getInt(4));
        despesa.setId(c.getInt(5));

        lista.add(despesa);
    }
    c.close();

    return lista;
}
```

O que está errado no código?
A variável `String a` recebe o valor correto da data, porém não é do tipo `Date`, como convertê-la para `Date` e exibi-la no formato **dd-mm-aaaa**?

GetView do Adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final int auxPosition = position;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditaDespesaActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("valor", lista.get(auxPosition).getValor());
            intent.putExtra("data", lista.get(auxPosition).getData());
            intent.putExtra("descricao", lista.get(auxPosition).getDescricao());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    TextView data = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.ddata);
    data.setText(lista.get(position).getData().toString());

    TextView desc = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.ddesc);
    desc.setText(lista.get(position).getDescricao());

    TextView valor = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.vvalor);
    valor.setText(lista.get(position).getValor().toString());

    return layout;
}
```

Método para salvar a despesa

```
public void salvarDespesa(View view){

    String[] data = etData.getText().toString().split("/");

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    despesa.setValor(Float.valueOf(etValor.getText().toString().substring(2,etValor.getText().toString().length()).replace(",", ".")));
    try {
        despesa.setData(dateFormat.parse(data[2]+ "-" + data[1]+ "-" + data[0]));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    despesa.setDescricao(etDesc.getText().toString());

    DespesaDAO despesaDAO = new DespesaDAO(this);
    despesaDAO.inserir(despesa);

    Toast.makeText(this,"Despesa adicionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    finish();
}
```

Comment: Como você está criando o item do layout? Usando o `ListAdapter`? Ou com um `Adapter` próprio? Se for um `Adapter` próprio, poderia incluir o método `getView` do seu `Adapter`?

Comment: Qual o formato que a Data está sendo salva no banco de dados?

Comment: DATETIME, eu seto lá no banco através de um DatePickerDialog. @Fernando

Comment: @AllanChrystian, [Não há o DataType `DATETIME` em SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), há métodos alternativos recomendados na documentação (Eu particularmente, recomendo e utilizo o com `INTEGER`, utilizando UNIX Time, posso postar um exemplo de como faço, se você achar que isso pode ser a causa ou ajudar?), talvez isso possa estar lhe confundindo e causando o problema.

Comment: Inserido método pra explicar melhor, acho que a resposta que você procurava era essa @Fernando

Comment: Acho que o problema não é no banco @Fernando, pois ao debugar vejo que o cursor retorna a data correta da inserção, só não estou conseguindo mostrar na tela.

Comment: @AllanChrystian, Tá ai, isso está incorreto conforme a [documentação](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime): `TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")`. Então você deve salvar nesse formato: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"

Comment: Não entendi @Fernando, poderia me explicar detalhadamente o que está errado no meu código?

Comment: @AllanChrystian, verifique no seu primeiro bloco de código, nesse trecho: `try { parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(a); a = parsedDate.toString(); } catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`, não está caindo no `catch`? Debug e nos informe.

Comment: @Fernando não cai no catch, ele executa porém mostra a data atual, não a data que foi setada na inserção da despesa.

Comment: Allan, o `lista.get(position).getData()` é um `Date` ou `Calendar`? Se for recomendo usar um `DateFormat` para formatar corretamente como `dd/MM/YYYY` ou algo do tipo.

Comment: É sim @Wakim, tipo Date, como eu faria essa conversão e como ficaria essa linha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para formatar um objeto `Date` de forma mais humana basta usar o `SimpleDateFormat`.

No construtor do seu `Adapter` basta criar uma instância:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

E usar no seu `getView` para formatar corretamente:

```
data.setText(sdf.format(lista.get(position).getData()));
```

**Obs**: Se quiser exibir a formatação de data correta para o idioma do dispositivo basta usar um dos métodos estáticos:

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance()
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
DateFormat.getTimeInstance()
```

A única diferença é ter de lidar com a superclasse (`DateFormat`) em vez da subclasse.

Qualquer coisa basta olhar melhor a documentação com diversos exemplos: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Resolveu! Obrigado pela resposta, muito bom.